# Link child and parent on the basic of depth level

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have all my parent children in a single array data.What i want is to add a new attribute (level) on  each objects.

Given i have data as

```
 var data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            parent_id: 0,
            name: "Child1",
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            parent_id: 1,
            name: "Child11",

        },

        {
            id: 5,
            parent_id: 4,
            name: "Child111",
        },
        {
            id: 11,
            parent_id: 4,
            name: "Child112"
        },


        {
            id: 13,
            parent_id: 11,
            name: "Child1121",
        },

        {
            id: 21,
            parent_id: 11,
            name: "Child1122"
        },
        {
            id: 22,
            parent_id: 11,
            name: "Child1123"
        },
        {
            id: 24,
            parent_id: 1,
            name: 'Child12'
        }

    ]
```

I want a **child-parent** relationship based on the *parent_id* of the children and assign a new attribute in each object of the array as level which represents the depth level of the children based on its parent.My **Expected** result is :

```
var data = [
            {
                id: 1,
                parent_id: 0, <-------represents root 
                name: "Child1",
                level:0   <--------level based on its parent_id 
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                parent_id: 1
                name: "Child11",
                level:1

            },
            {
                id: 5,
                parent_id: 4,
                name: "Child111",
                level:2
            },
            {
                id: 11,
                parent_id: 4,
                name: "Child112",
                level:2
            },


            {
                id: 13,
                parent_id: 11,
                name: "Child1121",
                level:3
            },

            {
                id: 21,
                parent_id: 11,
                name: "Child1122",
                level:3
            },
            {
                id: 22,
                parent_id: 11,
                name: "Child1123",
                level:3
            },
            {
                id: 24,
                parent_id: 1,
                name: 'Child12',
                level:1
            }

        ]
```

My Code

```
 function buildTree(elements, parent_id, level = 0) {

                elements.forEach(element => {


                    if (element['parent_id'] == parent_id) {
                        console.log('parent_id', parent_id);
                        // elements.filter(item=>item!==element);
                        element['level'] = level;

                    }
                    else{
                        buildTree(elements,parent_id,level+1);
                    }





                })




            return elements;




        }
```

Comment: do you have always sorted data?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes i do have always **sorted data**.

Answer (score 4):

For sorted data, you could take an object for the level count and map a new data set.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, parent_id: 0, name: "Child1" }, { id: 4, parent_id: 1, name: "Child11" }, { id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: "Child111" }, { id: 11, parent_id: 4, name: "Child112" }, { id: 13, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1121" }, { id: 21, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1122" }, { id: 22, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1123" }, { id: 24, parent_id: 1, name: 'Child12' }],
    levels = {},
    result = data.map(o => ({
        ...o,
        level: levels[o.id] = o.parent_id in levels
            ? levels[o.parent_id] + 1
            : 0
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let parentLevel = []

data.map(parent => {
    const { parent_id } = parent
    if (!parentLevel.includes(parent_id)) {
        parentLevel.push(parent_id);
    }
})

const updatedData = data.map(parent => {
    const { parent_id } = parent

    parent.level = parentLevel.indexOf(parent_id)

    return parent
})

console.log(updatedData);
```

The result is

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, parent_id: 0, name: "Child1", level: 0}
1: {id: 4, parent_id: 1, name: "Child11", level: 1}
2: {id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: "Child111", level: 2}
3: {id: 11, parent_id: 4, name: "Child112", level: 2}
4: {id: 13, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1121", level: 3}
5: {id: 21, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1122", level: 3}
6: {id: 22, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1123", level: 3}
7: {id: 24, parent_id: 1, name: "Child12", level: 1}
```

Comment: Wow love this.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If data is not sorted in a way that the parent is guaranteed to come before any of its children, then use a `Map` keyed by `id` values, which also gives better efficiency (no linear lookup in every iteration):

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, parent_id: 0, name: "Child1" }, { id: 4, parent_id: 1, name: "Child11" }, { id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: "Child111" }, { id: 11, parent_id: 4, name: "Child112" }, { id: 13, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1121" }, { id: 21, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1122" }, { id: 22, parent_id: 11, name: "Child1123" }, { id: 24, parent_id: 1, name: 'Child12' }];

// optional step if you don't want to mutate the original objects in the array:
data = data.map(o => ({...o}));

const map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.id, o])).set(0, { level: -1 });
const setLevel = o => "level" in o ? o.level : (o.level = 1 + setLevel(map.get(o.parent_id)));
data.forEach(setLevel);

console.log(data);
```

You can omit the optional assignment when you are OK with adding the `level` property to the existing objects. But if you want the original data objects to remain untouched, and have newly created objects for storing the `level` property, then keep that line in.